# save value of a variable in a DialogFragment when the screen rotates

Tags: android, rotation, fragment, screen, dialogfragment

Well, I wanted to save value of a variable contained in a dialogFragment when the screen is rotated in Android. I've tried every method I could find on the internet, and none of them has worked for me. Some kill my application, and others simply were not doing anything.

I need a real and effective way to save the value of an EditText that is reset when the device screen rotates. The EditText is in a DialogFragment turn this into a FragmentActivity.

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your fragment's `retaingInstance` flag to `true`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)

This prevents Fragment instance from being recreated.

Also be sure you don't recreate the fragment all the time:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Fragment f = new Myfragment();
        f.setRetainInstance(true);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, f))
            .commit();
    }

}
```

Since View state is preserved during Activity recreation and your are keeping the same Fragment instance you don't need to save TextView value all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question, but you can capture the rotation as follows:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        {
            //save value
        }
         if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {
            //save value
        } 
    }
```

If you want that your activity don't restart, you should add this into the manifest file:

```
<activity
            .....
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            ..... >
 </activity>
```

Comment: No, referring to something like 

`<!-- language: java -->`
`@Override`
 `public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){`
    ` super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);`
    ` outState.putString("precio", ` `txtPrecio.getText().toString());`
 `}`


 but this way has not worked for me, and the like either.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that you can not apply the methods to save bundles automatically to the dialogues, but these would apply to activities or fragments of these dialogues dependent. If I can fix it by code, will put the solution here. thank you